# remove everything that is not capital letter words from a string Regex rails

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a string

```
"WELLS FARGO DEALER SERVICES May 18 06:11 4137 Reference# 10982"
```

I want to remove everything so that I get

```
"WELLS FARGO DEALER SERVICES"
```

How can I do this with regex. I only want all cap words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace: `/\W*\b\w*[^\WA-Z]\w*/` with the empty string.

or to deal with unicode letters: `/\W*\b\w*[^\W\p{Lu}]\w*/u`

To trim the end of the string, you can add `|\W+\z` at the end. *(You can do the same kind of thing to trim the beginning)*

[demo](http://rubular.com/r/GmPbqsYQgY)

Comment: Excellent work! Tried a few strings and it did great! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is an enhancement to @CasimiretHippolyte excellent answer.

`(?:\W*\b\w*[^\WA-Z]\w*)+|(?<!\S)[^\S\r\n]+|\W+\z|\A\W+`

This groups his answer into a multi-quantified group.
It adds his BOL/EOL trim.

It also adds an extra trim on multiple whitespace, leaving a single space.
(this is incase there are multiple spaces between capital word groups).

Expanded

```
    (?: \W* \b \w* [^\WA-Z] \w* )+
 |  
    (?<! \S )
    [^\S\r\n]+ 
 |  
    \W+ \z 
 |  
    \A \W+
```

Answer (score 1):

```
str = "WELLS FARGO DEALER SERVICES May 18 06:11 4137 Reference# 10982"
```

If you want just one space between the all-cap words, it's just

```
str.split.select { |word| word =~ /\A[A-Z]+\z/ }.join(' ')
  #=> "WELLS FARGO DEALER SERVICES"
```